# Firestore - Do identical indexed field values could cause performance issues?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Do identical indexed field values could cause performance issues?
Is a current minute sequential value that could cause hotspots? (indexed fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing you can do will cause *read* performance issues. That is one of the main guarantees that Firestore gives you.

But it *is* possible to create *write* performance bottlenecks, by forcing Firestore to write lots of data to the same physical location (or nearby locations) on disk. One common way to do that is by having an index on a field that has is not uniformly distributed, such as the scenario you're describing.

So: yes, having an indexed field on a time-based field can affect write throughput. The less granular the field's values, the sooner you'll hit throughput limits.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest that "high *read* or write rates" are also subject to hotspotting. If reads never cause performance issues, then I'm a bit confused: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range